# Two names and a code

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, geography

Two male friends were on a vacation at their favourite holiday destination. There they came across two women who were on vacation as well. With the hope of getting to know them and possibly get their mobile numbers, the male friends approached them.

The four of them had a good chat and the women disclosed most of the things except for their names, nationalities and mobile numbers.

When they were leaving, one of the women handed over a note to one of the men. Her friend did the same with the other man. The notes contained the clues about those two women.

---

**Note from woman 1**

- *Me and my friend are from the same country.*
- *All the letters in my name appear in the name of my country as well.*
- *'The Simpsons' is your clue.*
- *The required code for my mobile number is a perfect square.*
- *Find my name and the code for a date with me and to possibly acquire my mobile number.*

---

**Note from woman 2**

- *Me and my friend are from the same country.*
- *All the letters in my name appear in the name of my country as well.*
- *'The Big Bang Theory' is your clue.*
- *The required code for my mobile number is a perfect square.*
- *Find my name and the code for a date with me and to possibly acquire my mobile number.*

---

The two male friends discussed together and managed to correctly find the required details.

***Can you find the women's details from those notes?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first glance this puzzle actually looks more complex than it is. Consider what you're truly being asked to find, and (since both women are from the same country) really it's a case of finding...

> ...a single country whose international dialling code is a square number, and whose name spelled out in English contains the letters from two women's names, where one has some connection to *The Simpsons* and the other has a connection to *The Big Bang Theory*.

With a little knowledge of both shows (and by consulting [a list of dialling codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes)), it is a short hop to find that both women must be from:

> **GERMANY**, where the international dialling code is **+49** (i.e. 7 squared), and that the women's names must be **[MARGE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marge_Simpson)** and **[AMY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amy_Farrah_Fowler)**.

Comment: Yeah. Passing notes that say "Find my name and the code for a date with me to possibly acquire my mobile number" sounds very much like girls from that country.